# Unification of two or more Git repositories in a single one

Tags: git

I have to unify two (maybe more) Git repositories in a single one.

The given repositories are A, B, etc. All the files and folders from these repositories at the end must be an X, with the following structure:

```
X
|- .git
|-A
|-B
...
```

In this X, the subfolders (A, B, ...) **must not contain** the initial .git subfolder. All the history information **must go in the root** .git of the X repository.

Obviously, the repositories (A, B, ...) have many branches, tags, etc.
At the end, the Git log of the X must contain the initail logs from A, B, etc, in chronological order.

This unification is it possible? If yes, how should I proceed?

KI

Comment: Possible, but commit hashes will change and if you have signed commits, you'll loose the signatures. This looks promising: http://choly.ca/post/git-merge-to-monorepo/

Comment: this is technically difficult, and you may not get all the things you want. consider for instance, where is HEAD, since you want both repos to have their own main, and sub branches, and the commits on both trees will have no relation to each other? looks messy.

Comment: Note that a MonoRepo is a specific thing so please review to make sure its right for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monorepo#:~:text=In%20version%2Dcontrol%20systems%2C%20a,commonly%20called%20a%20shared%20codebase.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but more and more unpleasant with every new branch.

Simplified algorithm for only master/main branches:

```bash
mkdir new-repo
cd new-repo
git init
git remote add o1 https://github.com/sienori/simple-translate.git
git remote add o2 https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky.git
git fetch o1
git fetch o2
git merge o1/master
shopt -s dotglob
mkdir A
git mv * A -k
git commit -m repo1
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories o2/main
mkdir B
git mv !(A) B -k
git commit -m repo2
```

In case you really want to save all branches:

1. Before merging: find in both repositories not very old commit - common parent for all branches that will be transferred to unified repo and create branch there.
2. Execute algorithm from first part of the answer using branches created on step 1 instead master/main.
3. For every branch of both repositories execute rebase.